# Breadth first or depth first search for finding a child at a particular depth?

Tags: algorithm, graph, binary-search-tree

I know there are lots of questions on here dealing with Breadth First Search vs Depth First Search, but I think that my situation is a little different.

I have a rooted tree in which each node may have 0, 1 or 2 children (with the expected number being 1).  Given a large number `n`, I want to find a path through the tree of length `n`.

It seems clear that depth-first should be the best way to do this, but I'm not so sure.  The width of the tree is very small, which is normally a reason to use breadth first search.  In addition, if I use depth first search, then I could end up following going down into a subtree whose height is very close to `n`, but smaller than `n`.  In that case, I will waste a lot of time traversing a tree that can't possibly give me the answer I want

Comment: I would suggest you look at iterative deepening depth first search.

Comment: you might wanna look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332947/when-is-it-practical-to-use-dfs-vs-bfs

Comment: @marvel308 I have, and I have referred to what I found out there in the question.

Comment: @RudraniAngira Isn't that worse than depth first search?  In order to find a node at depth `n`, I have to search the entire tree up to depth `n-1`.  A depth first search would certainly be preferable to that.

Comment: @JohnGowers IDDFS would stop at the depth where your goal state would be.

Comment: @RudraniAngira Yes it would, but before it did that it would have to search through much more of the tree than a simple depth-first search would.

Comment: You say you want to find **a** path. Is this a one-time query, or are you going to need to find multiple paths (with possibly different values of `n`) in the same tree? If this is a one-time thing, since the worst-case performance of the two searches is the same, I would suggest you compare the best-case performance.

Comment: This is a one time query.  I think you're right, though: with depth first search, there's a chance that we have to search through more of the tree than we want to.  But with breadth first search, that happens all the time.

Comment: With no extra information of the tree, assuming it has no special ordering or structure, I do not think you can do better than O(M) where M is the # of nodes of the tree and M > n. If the construction of the tree can be modified, then you may store the height of the subtree rooted at a node when building the tree, then you can achieve O(n) easily in this one time query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. DFS will always be more efficient than BFS for your goal. since BFS iterate over *all* nodes in depth 1, then all the nodes in depth 2, and so on, in order to find a path of length n, BFS will first travel through all paths in the tree of length <= n-1. in the absolute worst case, DFS will do the same until finding the requested path, but in the general case, DFS will be far more efficiently in my opinion.
2. I know that's not always possible, but of you can change your tree implementation so that every node will contain the length of it's sub-tree (the max value between the node's children), it'll will solve your problem and is very easy to maintain during regular insert\remove etc.