# PHP recursive foreach with left, right and depth

Tags: php, json, recursion, foreach

I have a json file taken from geonames.org and I want to add the data from that file using **php recursive foreach**.

I only succeeded that I just did not understand the concept of left right depth. Depth is saved correctly.

My code is:

```
public function buildTree($elements, $count = 1, $depth = 0)
    {
        if (isset($elements->geonames)) {
            foreach ($elements->geonames as $element) {
                $left = $count++;

                $elementDB = new \App\Geo();

                $elementDB->id        = $element->geonameId;
                $elementDB->parent_id  = NULL;
                $elementDB->left      = $left;
                $elementDB->right     = $right;
                $elementDB->depth     = $depth;
                $elementDB->name      = $element->name;
                $elementDB->country   = $element->countryCode;
                $elementDB->level     = $element->fcode;
                $elementDB->lat       = $element->lat;
                $elementDB->long      = $element->lng;
                $elementDB->save();

                $elements = $this->getList($element->geonameId, 'element');

                if ($depth < 1) {
                    $this->buildTree($elements, $count, $depth + 1);
                }

                $right = $count++;

                echo "Added element " . $element->name . "\n";
            }
        }
    }
```

[This should happen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2iPwV.jpg)

Comment: And what is not working with the given code?

Comment: No, it does not work.

Comment: What **exactly** does that mean? What do you expect from that code? What have you tried to debug the problem?

Comment: I've added a picture of what's going to happen.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems you want to understand how it works? 
You use recursion to process every element. Variable $elements is a tree (or sub-tree) with nodes. Your code has to look through your tree from left to right. On every iteration you check if $elements has nodes. If $elements has (it might be ordered array or struct with fields) nodes you have to process those nodes. During every checking you detect every node if they have other children nodes or not. When you find the first (let's name it "A") node that has other children nodes you have to go into on next iteration recursion to process children nodes of current child node ("A").
[image]

The numbers represent the order in which the nodes are accessed in Left-Right depth algorithm.

Frankly speaking I don't understand for what you have added:

```
$this->buildTree($elements, $count, $depth + 1);
```

And it's a bad style reassignment for variable in **foreach**:
[image]

May be it will be interesting for you [When is it practical to use Depth-First Search (DFS) vs Breadth-First Search (BFS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332947/when-is-it-practical-to-use-depth-first-search-dfs-vs-breadth-first-search-bf)

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming here you're making a binary search tree. Basically, a tree is a graph with a root, "regular" nodes, and leaves.

There's always one single root, at the top, which is a particular node.

Leaves don't have other nodes below, they are the "ends" of the tree.

Regular nodes have possibly two children, one smaller (on the left) and one bigger (on the right). This makes something like that:

[image]

As you can see, all nodes coming from the left child of the root are smaller than 8. All children on the right are bigger than 8. This way, when you search for "10", you immediatly know that you have to go through the right child of the root, no need the explore left side (that means less processing time).

Answer (score 1):

A possible binary search tree search algorithm implementation is as follows:

```
function buildTree($elements, $left, $right, $needle){
    if ($left > $right) return null;
    $middle = floor(($left + $right) / 2);
    $val = $elements[$middle];
    if ($val === $needle) return $val;
    else if ($val < $needle) return buildTree($elements, $left + 1, $right, $needle);
    else if ($val > $needle) return buildTree($elements, $left, $right + 1, $needle);
}

echo buildTree([1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 0, 5, 4);
```

You just need to adapt this to your problem