# BFS and DFS disadvantages

Tags: tree, depth-first-search, breadth-first-search

BFS consumes a lot of memory especially when the branching factor of the tree is huge. DFS, on the other hand, may take a long time to visit other neighbouring nodes if the depth of the tree is huge, but it has better space-complexity. For example, in BFS, if I have a branching factor of 10 and depth of 12, using the formula `O(b^d)`, it means I'll have around 10^12 nodes. If each node is 10Bytes, it'll need around 10TB.

However, what is considered 'huge' here? Is a 10TB space-complexity considered huge (I'm pretty sure it is, though)? How do I determine when I should leave DFS and BFS and look for other algorithms? Are they even still used in modern applications or are some other better algorithms applied instead (like IDDFS)?

Answer (score 0):

Consider this source: [When is it practical to use Depth-First Search (DFS) vs Breadth-First Search (BFS)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3332947/when-is-it-practical-to-use-depth-first-search-dfs-vs-breadth-first-search-bf)

I think there are experiment for your own data, resources. If the result of test case is not satisfying for you, try another algorithm. Binary-Tree Search, KDTree is some options.

If the memory is limited, try to use Disk to save the current state of search.