# Advantage of depth first search over breadth first search or vice versa

Tags: algorithm, graph, graph-algorithm

I have studied the two graph traversal algorithms,depth first search and breadth first search.Since both algorithms are used to solve the same problem of graph traversal I would like to know how to choose between the two.I mean is one more efficient than the other or any reason why i would choose one over the other in a particular scenario ?

Thank You

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/687731/breadth-first-vs-depth-first  ...contains some useful info and links, including 3 part blog linked to in one of the last two answers.

Comment: Thanks for sharing this.It looks really helpful.Actually, i do understand how both algorithms work, just want to know why we need two of them :)

Comment: similar to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1657174/what-is-breadth-first-search-useful-for

Comment: possible duplicate of [Graphs data structure: DFS vs BFS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2626198/graphs-data-structure-dfs-vs-bfs)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Main difference to me is somewhat theoretical. If you had an infinite sized graph then DFS would never find an element if it exists outside of the first path it chooses. It would essentially keep going down the first path and would never find the element. The BFS would eventually find the element.

If the size of the graph is finite, DFS would likely find a outlier (larger distance between root and goal) element faster where BFS would find a closer element faster. Except in the case where DFS chooses the path of the shallow element.

Comment: This is not a bad answer, but DFS and BFS can both fail in the infinite case - DFS can fail if a graph is infinitely deep, while BFS can work. However, DFS will work if the graph is not infinitely deep, but infinitely *broad* - while BFS will fail. Traversing infinite graphs (from what I understand) is much different than traversing finite graphs.

Answer (score 9):

In general, BFS is better for problems related to finding the shortest paths or somewhat related problems. Because here you go from one node to all node that are adjacent to it and hence you effectively move from path length one to path length two and so on.

While DFS on the other end helps more in connectivity problems and also in finding cycles in graph(though I think you might be able to find cycles with a bit of modification of BFS too). Determining connectivity with DFS is trivial, if you call the explore procedure twice from the DFS procedure, then the graph is disconnected (this is for an undirected graph). You can see the strongly connected component algorithm for a directed graph here, which is a modification of DFS. Another application of the DFS is topological sorting.

These are some applications of both the algorithms:

DFS:

Connectivity
Strongly Connected Components
Topological Sorting

BFS:

Shortest Path(Dijkstra is some what of a modification of BFS).
Testing whether the graph is Bipartitie.

Answer (score 0):

For a complete/perfect tree, DFS takes a linear amount of space with respect to the depth of the tree whereas BFS takes an exponential amount of space with respect to the depth of the tree. This is because for BFS the maximum number of nodes in the queue is proportional to the number of nodes in one level of the tree. In DFS the maximum number of nodes in the stack is proportional to the depth of the tree.

Answer (score 0):

When traversing a multiply-connected graph, the order in which nodes are traversed may greatly influence (by many orders of magnitude) the number of nodes to be tracked by the traversing method.  Some kinds of algorithms will be massively better when using breadth-first; others will be massively better when using depth-search.

At one extreme, doing a depth-first search on a binary tree with N leaf nodes requires that the traversing method keep track of lgN nodes while a breadth-first search would require keeping track of at least N/2 nodes (since it might scan all other nodes before it scans any leaf nodes; immediately prior to scanning the first leaf node, it would have encountered N/2 of the leafs' parent nodes which have to be tracked separately since none of them reference each other).

On the other extreme, doing a flood-fill on an NxN grid with a method that, if its pixel hasn't been colored yet, colors that pixel and then flood-fills its neighbors will require enqueuing O(N) pixel coordinates if using breadth-first search, but O(N^2) pixel coordinates if using depth-first.  When using breadth-first search, paint will seem to "spread out", regardless of the shape to be painted; when using depth-first algorithm to paint a rectangular spiral, each line of which is straight on one side and jagged on the other (which sides should be straight and jagged depends upon the exact algorithm used), all of the straight sections will get painted before any of the jagged ones, meaning that the system must track the location of every jag separately.